# Assign value to property in the field but not in constructor in typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

It is working  if I  assign value to property in the field, but not in the constructor in typescript, as `proda = this.navParams.data;` in the field. I try this and it seems to be working in my ionic page .ts file.

It is the correct original code below:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the BuyoutPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-buyout',
  templateUrl: 'buyout.html',
})
export class BuyoutPage {

  proda;    

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.proda = this.navParams.data;
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad BuyoutPage');
  }

  onConfirm(){
    this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
  }

}
```

It is the code that I tried to assign value to the field but not in constructor, and seems to work:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the BuyoutPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-buyout',
  templateUrl: 'buyout.html',
})
export class BuyoutPage {

  proda = this.navParams.data;  

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad BuyoutPage');
  }

  onConfirm(){
    this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm confused: you said that assigning to the property in the constructor did not work, but you say the code snippet works and it assigns to the property in the constructor.  When you say that assigning "did not work", what went wrong?  Did you get wrong data somewhere, or an error?

Comment: Sorry for bad expression, I have edited the post

Comment: So both versions of the code work?  Then what is your question?